# Where to find GCMBaseIntentService in new google play services?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

gcm is google play services now! can u guys please provide where can i find GCMBaseIntentService..am not able to import it. I am following some tutorial which was on gcm. i am just trying to convert that with a new play serveces. Thanks in adv.

Comment: you have to import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging by making a reference to Google Play Services to use GCMIntentService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following steps.

1. Download "Google Play Service" extras using SDK manager.
2. Import library project resides in `<android-sdk>\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib`.
3. Add that [library project to your project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject).
4. Follow steps how to [Implementing GCM Client](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

Comment: gcm.jar is deprecated. I am not able to find the jar. and not able to find any tutorial for push notifications using google play services sdk :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `gcm.jar` file in you app libs folder, if libs folder not available you have to create one folder in your app and add this jar in that.